# generic "out of bounds", "past end" iterator

Tags: c++, tree, iterator

In my application I have a (unbalanced) tree datastructure. This tree is simply made of "std::list of std::lists" - node holds an arbitrary "list" of sub-nodes. Using this instead of a single list made the rest of the application a lot easier. (The program is about changing moving nodes from one tree to another tree / another part in the tree / to it's own tree).

Now an obvious task is to find a subtree inside a "tree". For non-recursive searches it is simple enough:

```
subtree_iterator find_subtree(const N& n) {         
    auto iter(subtrees.begin());
    auto e(subtrees.end());
    while (iter != e) {
        if ((*iter)->name == n) {
            return iter;
        }
        ++iter;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Which returns an iterator to the subtree position. The problem however starts when I try to implement a multi-level search. Ie, I wish to search for `hello.world.test` where the dots mark a new level.

Searching worked alright

```
subtree_iterator find_subtree(const pTree_type& otree, std::string identify) const {
    pTree_type tree(otree);
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(".");
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokens(identify, sep);
    auto token_iter(tokens.begin());
    auto token_end(tokens.end());

    subtree_iterator subtree_iter;
    for (auto token_iter(tokens.begin()); token_iter != token_end; ++token_iter) {
        std::string subtree_string(*token_iter);
        subtree_iter = tree->find_subtree_if(subtree_string);
        if (subtree_iter == tree->subtree_end()) {
            return otree->subtree_end()
        } else {
            tree = *subtree_iter;
        }
    }
    return subtree_iter;
}
```

On first glace it seemed to work "correct", however when I try to use it, it fails.  Using it would be like

```
auto tIn(find_subtree(ProjectTree, "hello.world.test"));
if (tIn != ProjectTree->subtree_end()) {
    //rest
}
```

however that gives a debug assertion error "list iterators not compatible". This isn't too weird: I'm comparing a iterators from different lists to each other. However I could I implement such a thing? My "backup" option would be to return a `std::pair<bool,iterator>` where the boolean part determines if the tree actually exists. Is there another method, short of making the whole tree single list?

Comment: If you do decide to make the whole thing one list, not that you can use `list::splice` to move pieces of it around.

Comment: @ymett hmm forgot that one - though as in my project it is very usefull to always consider a node a tree on itself. Using a single list to hold all subtrees would mean that 1 node is the "root" & "special".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not work on iterators internaly. Use nodes instead.

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
 T item;
 Node<T>* next;
};
```

Then encapsulate your Node in an iterator facade like this :

```
template<typename T>
class iterator {
private:
  Node<T>* node;
public:
  ...
};
```

Then use a generic invalid node (when node is nullptr) that is returned whenever end() is reached or returned.
Note that what i suggest is a single linked list (not double linked list as the standard one). this is because you can't go back from an invalid generic end() iterator that point to an invalid null node.
If you don't use iterator operator--() in your algorithms this should be fine.

Comment: So basically write my own iterator class? Should this derive from forward_iterator class?

Comment: I don't think that forward_iterator is standard. so you don't need to.
Just make sure it complies with the ForwardIterator concept (which is really basic). See : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator

Comment: Well just tried to implement it and it opens a whole other can of worms :P. I take it that by using that 'node' you meant to replace the std::list-system for subtrees? However without a decrement operator removing a node at the middle of the list is "expensive".. I guess it is not possible to use such a custom iterator class with `std::list` containers?

Comment: is not really so much expensive... just copy the next node to the one to be deleted and delete the next node instead... you just have to check that you are not deleting the last node...

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<list_iterator>` stack to traverse?  Where the `.back()` of the stack is the only one allowed to be equal to `end()` of the previous one, and `.front()` is an iterator to the root `list`?